# How to read Linux "martian source" logs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, iptables, routing, bridge

I'm setting up KVM virtualization host with policy based routing (192.168.1.0/24 management network for host related traffic like updates,ssh etc, 192.168.2.0/24 DMZ network routed to VMs)

Setup looks like this (by ^^^ i mean *like above* to represent tree structure)

```
#external connectivity
eth0 -> vlan110 -> brhost (192.168.1.9)
^^^  -> vlan120 -> brguest (192.168.2.4)

#internal connectivity
brguestA (10.0.1.1) -> tapA0
^^^                 -> tapA1
^^^                 -> tapA2
brguestB (10.0.2.1) -> tapB0
^^^                 -> tapB1

# ... and so on for each VM group subnet
```

machines An are in one "switch", Bn in second one etc. Host behaves like router and has iptables installed. Source ip is validated per bridge on iptables level.

In general everything "normal" works but when I'm performing some border case operations it still behaves the way it should, but logs suggest that it's more of coincidence than actual proper functioning. For example:

- connecting to 192.168.1.3 from VM (different host in management network) which is blocked operation on iptables level (tcp-reset) gives

  ```
  (iptables reject log) IN=brguestA OUT=brguest SRC=10.0.1.2 DST=192.168.1.3 ...
  IPv4: martian source 10.0.1.2 from 192.168.1.3 on dev brhost
  ```

note that `OUT` interface is actually correct according to what it should do considering logic of host/guest networking separation and even if such packets would be forwarded by host they'd get dropped on firewall anyways. Nevertheless host iptables can't properly reject with tcp-reset so such connections just hang on VM and don't receive reset

- connecting to 192.168.1.9 from VM gives

  ```
  IPv4: martian source 192.168.1.9 from 10.0.1.2 on dev brguestA
  ```

and nothing else. Swapping places of 10.0.1.x and 192.168.1.x in those logs makes me really confused and I don't really understand what is meaning of those (which ones is src ip and which one is dst ip). I don't really know what host is trying to do and why it fails. Here's output of my `ip rule` and `ip route`:

```
ip rule
0: from all lookup local
32763: from 10.0.0.0/16 lookup guest
32764: from 192.168.2.0/24 lookup guest
32765: from all iif lo lookup host
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default

ip route show table host
default via 192.168.1.1 dev brhost proto static
192.168.1.0/24 dev brhost proto static

ip route show table guest
default via 192.168.2.1 dev brguest proto static
10.0.0.0/24 dev brguestA proto static
10.0.1.0/24 dev brguestB proto static
# ... so on for other networks

ip route show table main
192.168.1.0/24 dev brhost proto static
10.0.0.0/24 dev brguestA proto static
10.0.1.0/24 dev brguestB proto static
# ...
```

I'm using `systemd-networkd` for network management. I *thought* it is happening because host always tries to respond using `brhost` device as being `OUTPUT` type of packet it has `iif` set to `lo` so it's caught by `from iif lookup host` rule. However it doesn't seem to be a case as connecting to `192.168.2.4` is rejected properly so it doens't always pick `brhost` as output source.